# vba macro with 3 command buttons linked with each other

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, commandbutton

How to apply a macro function with three command buttons ? I tried with below code.. but returns the macro applied on different sheet.

cmd button1: browses the main raw data file.

cmd button2: vlookup data file for the main raw data file.

cmd button3: Run the macro below function on the main raw data file.

your ideas will be much helpful.. thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit
Sub currentZOE3()
'declare variable to store path

Dim Get_Path As String

    Dim fileExplorer As FileDialog
    Set fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'To allow or disable to multi select
    fileExplorer.AllowMultiSelect = False

    With fileExplorer

If .Show <> 0 Then
Get_Path = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 4).Value = Get_Path

End With

End Sub
Sub lastweekZOE3()

'declare variable to store path

Dim Get_Path As String

    Dim fileExplorer As FileDialog
    Set fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'To allow or disable to multi select
    fileExplorer.AllowMultiSelect = False

    With fileExplorer

If .Show <> 0 Then
Get_Path = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(5, 4).Value = Get_Path

End With

End Sub

Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'

Dim updWb As Workbook
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Set updWb = Workbooks.Open(Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 4).Value)
Set DSheet = updWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Cells.Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 13
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
'
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    Columns("Q:S").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("Q1") = "Concantenate"
    Range("R1") = "Delivery Plan"
    Range("S1") = "Last Week Comments"
    Range("Q2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-16]&RC[-9]&RC[-7]"
    Range("S2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[Last Week.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,0)"
    Range("R2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFS(RC22=""YBWR"",""What"",ISNUMBER(RC25),""Fully Delivered"",RC19=""Billable Only"",""BILLABLE ONLY"",AND(ISBLANK(RC25),NOT(ISBLANK(RC27))),""Under shipment"",AND(ISBLANK(RC25),ISBLANK(RC27),ISNUMBER(RC14)),""Under packing"",AND(ISBLANK(RC25),ISBLANK(RC27),ISBLANK(RC14)),TEXT(WEEKNUM(RC23),""W00""))"
    Range("P3").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("Q8833:S8833").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Cells.Select
    Range("Q8833").Activate
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit

    With Cells
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      "=($R1=""What"")"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 12173758
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        StopIfTrue = False
    End With
     End With

     With Cells
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      "=($R1=""Fully Delivered"")"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 5691552
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        StopIfTrue = False
    End With
     End With

     With Cells
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      "=($R1=""under shipment"")"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 3774674
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        StopIfTrue = False
    End With
     End With

     With Cells
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      "=($R1=""under packing"")"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 15793920
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        StopIfTrue = False
    End With
     End With

    Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
    Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

        Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("A1:A8837"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BE$8837").AutoFilter Field:=1

    'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim pvtfield As PivotField

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)


'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="PivotTable")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")

'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Sold to name")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Sales Document")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Customer purchase order number")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 3
End With

'Insert Column Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Delivery Plan")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
End With

'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("SO Net value")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = " Sum SO Net value "
End With

'classic and expand/collapse button removal

Range("C7").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable")
        .InGridDropZones = True
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    End With
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").ShowDrillIndicators = False


'Format Pivot
TableActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = TrueActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"


End Sub
```

Comment: Because nowhere in your `Sub Macro4()` you have entered which sheet to update. You are performing operations using `ActiveSheet` and thus code is updating the activesheet.

Comment: @stud3nt how do I call the file which is browsed from cmd button 1 & 2?? thats where im confused and raised... couldnt find any references either...

Comment: Sure, I have added an answer. Please go through the guide - [ask] and [mre]. Make sure you don't add all your code which is not required in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the path of the file using the `FileDialog` method. 
You can use the below function to open that excel and update the contents of it's worksheets.

```vb
Dim updWb As Workbook, wSheet As Worksheet
Set updWb = Workbooks.Open("<path of the workbook to be updated>")
Set wSheet = updWb.Sheets("<sheet-name> or <sheet-index>")
```

Comment: Referring the above I understand the path should be manually entered in the script... but I need the path to be picked from Sub currentZOE3() and vlookup file ref path from Sub lastweekZOE3() which are each seperate cmd buttons.

Comment: You can return a value from Sub and use it to get the path. Myabe I didn't get your question. Arn't you able to get the path from `Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 4).Value` ?

Comment: I came upto this and got compile error. please refer my latest edit.

Comment: Where are you getting the compile error ? Also, can you debug and see if the value you are getting in `Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 4).Value` is correct ?

Comment: `wSheet As Worksheet` returns statement invalid outside type block.

Comment: It should be `Dim wSheet As Worksheet` in case it is a new line.

Comment: I have done my edits brother. sorry for not notifying. it still shows error. compile error: variable not defined. at `StopIfTrue = False` Im working on it but cant find a solution.

Comment: Please compile the vba and fix all the undefined variables. Otherwise remove `Option Explicit` to ignore variable declaration.